# transfer app from one azure account to another

Tags: azure

We are currently developing an app hosted on Azure under a developer's MSDN account on a small instance. We'd like to set up a paying account to make provisioning more resources easier. Is there a way to do this? Or do we need to create a new app under the new account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can move do it yourself per se, you are correct in that you will have to re-create and deploy on the other account.

Alternatively it might be worth contacting support, I think they are able to move it for you or at least they used to.

Comment: Azure support can move everything from one account to a completely empty new account, but they can't move things into an account that already has things attached to it.  It's shockingly poor.